# How can I generate a map of all initialized variables from an object in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, properties, dictionary, member

I have a large list of java objects that all inherit from one shared object and each contains many field members (properties). However, not all fields on all of the objects are guaranteed to be initialized. There are also fields that are contained in the super class which should be included as well. I am looking to create a map that contains all of the initialized members with the member's identifier as the key and their value and the map value.

Is this even possible? I have looked briefly into reflection which looked promising but I do not have much experience with it. All of the values are primitive value types and could be stored in strings if necessary.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Well I am trying to get a general direction for now. I have been googling for related questions and I haven't come across much. Is it even possible to iterate over all members of an object at runtime in Java?

Comment: It is indeed [possible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields()). If you want to learn more about reflection, you might want to take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: great! I'll start there. Thanks

Comment: "not all fields on all of the objects are guaranteed to be initialized" the constructors of your classes should produce initialized objects. Then you wouldn't have this kind of problem.

Comment: Ok, that may have been poor wording. I suppose that all fields will be initialized... but many may be null. As well as not all objects in the list will contain the same fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
    public void method method(Object obj) {
        Map initializedFieldsMap = new HashMap();

        for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            Boolean acessibleState = field.isAccessible();
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value;
            try {
                value = field.get(obj);
                if (value != null) {
                    initializedFieldsMap.put(field.getName(), new WeakReference(value));
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            }
            field.setAccessible(acessibleState);
        }
        return initializedFieldsMap;
    }
```

It's using a [WeakReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) here so the object value won't get "stucked" (but it's still not ideal) and ineligible to GC, to access a value (String for instance) from the Map  use:

`String xxx = (String)map.get("value").get();`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I believe this is mostly what I needed. I also found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665689/2410503) which complements this nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers that I found:

```
public  static Map<String, String> generatePropertiesMap(Object o)
{
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (Field field : getAllDeclaredFields(o)) {
        Boolean acessibleState = field.isAccessible();
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value;
        try {
            value = field.get(o);
            if (value != null) {
                properties.put(field.getName(), value.toString());
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }
        field.setAccessible(acessibleState);
    }

    return properties;
}

private static List<Field> getAllDeclaredFields(Object o) {
    List<Field> list = new ArrayList<Field>();
    List<Field[]> fields = new ArrayList<Field[]>();

    //work up from this class until Object
    Class next = o.getClass();
    while (true) {
        Field[] f = next.getDeclaredFields();
        fields.add(f);
        next = next.getSuperclass();
        if (next.equals(Object.class))
            break;
    }

    for (Field[] f : fields) {
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(f));
    }
    return list;
}
```